# Check Accounting Journal for Errors

Tags: beginner, vba, excel, validation

I wrote this sub in Excel VBA.  I am a novice, but I was able to get my code to work how I wanted it to.

Unfortunately, I can see there is a lot of repetition, but it is too complex for me to figure out how to extract the duplicate if statements.

I am sure there is a lot of other issues with my code, but the repetitive if statements was what brought me to this site to look for help in refactoring.

This first section I just made it `Option Explicit` so I wouldn't mess up with variables.  Then I declared some Public variables that I needed to use in a couple of modules.

The main sub is ErrorCheck which validates data in numerous ranges on the worksheet.  Many of the if statements are repetitive, but they have enough differences like ranges and diff msgbox answers where I don't know how to extract as a separate function or sub.

```
Option Explicit
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean

Private Sub disable()
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False

        CalcState = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        EventState = .EnableEvents
        .EnableEvents = False

        PageBreakState = Sheet2.DisplayPageBreaks
        Sheet2.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub enable()
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcState
        .EnableEvents = EventState
        Sheet2.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
    End With
End Sub

Sub ErrorCheck()

    'call disable routine to speed up macro
    disable

    On Error Resume Next
    'unprotect sheet to avoid any issues
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "secret"

    'hide export in case changes were made
    Sheet2.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 3").Visible = msoFalse

    'make sure there are at least a debit and credit entered
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow < 9 Then
        MsgBox ("Journal Entries require a minimum of 2 transactions")
        GoTo SafeExit
    End If

    'input item numbers in column C
    Dim ItemRng As Range
    Set ItemRng = Range("C8:C" & LastRow)
    Range("C8").value = 1
    ItemRng.DataSeries Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Trend:=False

    'make all debit and credit entries uppercase
    With Range("E8:E" & LastRow)
        .value = Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)")
    End With

    'get rid of all negative amounts
    With Range("F8:F" & LastRow)
        .value = Evaluate("INDEX(ABS(" & .Address(External:=True) & "),)")
    End With

    'check main fields are populated
    Dim MainRng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set MainRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5, D2:D3, D8:F" & LastRow & ", J8:K" & LastRow)
    For Each rng In MainRng
        If rng.value = "" Then
            MsgBox (Cells(7, rng.Column) & " is a required field " & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
            rng.Select
            GoTo SafeExit
        End If
        If Not Intersect(rng, Range("D8:D" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
            If IsError(Application.VLookup(Val(rng.value), Range("SAP_COA"), 1, False)) Then
                MsgBox "This is not a valid GL account" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                rng.Select
                GoTo SafeExit
            End If
        End If
        If Not Intersect(rng, Range("E8:E" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
            If IsError(Application.VLookup(rng.value, Range("Indicator"), 1, False)) Then
                MsgBox "This is not a valid Debit/Credit indicator" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                rng.Select
                GoTo SafeExit
            End If
        End If
        If Not Intersect(rng, Range("K8:K" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
            If IsError(Application.VLookup(Val(rng.value), Range("Code"), 1, False)) Then
                MsgBox "This is not a valid Company Code" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                rng.Select
                GoTo SafeExit
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Dim RefRng As Range
    Dim GLRng As Range
    Dim CenterRng As Range
    Set GLRng = Range("D8:D" & LastRow)

    If Sheet2.CheckBox1.value = True Then
        For Each rng In GLRng
            If Left(rng.value, 1) <> 6 Then
                Set CenterRng = Range("Y" & rng.Row)
                If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(CenterRng) > 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Please enter a profit center" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & CenterRng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False))
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    CenterRng.Select
                    GoTo SafeExit
                End If
            End If
            If Left(rng.value, 1) = 4 Or Left(rng.value, 1) = 5 Then
                Set RefRng = Range("M" & rng.Row & ":T" & rng.Row)
                If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(RefRng) > 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Reference 1 or Reference 2 is required for P&L accounts")
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    RefRng.Select
                    GoTo SafeExit
                End If

                If Len(Range("M" & rng.Row).value) > 0 And Len(Range("M" & rng.Row).value) <> 4 Then
                    MsgBox "SubVendor and Master Vendor must be 4 digits." & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("M" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    Range("M" & rng.Row).Select
                    GoTo SafeExit
                End If

                If Len(Range("N" & rng.Row).value) > 0 And Len(Range("N" & rng.Row).value) <> 4 Then
                    MsgBox "SubVendor and Master Vendor must be 4 digits." & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("N" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    Range("N" & rng.Row).Select
                    GoTo SafeExit
                End If

                If Len(Range("Q" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If Len(Range("Q" & rng.Row).value) <> 8 And Len(Range("Q" & rng.Row).value) <> 6 Then
                        MsgBox "Customer account number is 8 digits or SAP account number is 6 digits" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("Q" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("Q" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

                If Len(Range("R" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If Len(Range("R" & rng.Row).value) <> 8 And Len(Range("R" & rng.Row).value) <> 6 Then
                        MsgBox "Customer account number is 8 digits or SAP account number is 6 digits" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("R" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("R" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

                If Len(Range("O" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Range("O" & rng.Row).value, Range("BU"), 1, False)) Then
                        MsgBox UCase(Range("O" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Business Unit" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("O" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("O" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

                If Len(Range("P" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Range("P" & rng.Row).value, Range("VD"), 1, False)) Then
                        MsgBox UCase(Range("P" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Vendor Division" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("P" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("P" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

                If Len(Range("S" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Range("S" & rng.Row).value, Range("Cus_Group"), 1, False)) Then
                        MsgBox UCase(Range("S" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Customer Group" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("S" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("S" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

                If Len(Range("T" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Range("T" & rng.Row).value, Range("Cus_Seg"), 1, False)) Then
                        MsgBox UCase(Range("T" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Customer Segment" & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("T" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("T" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

                If Len(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Val(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value), Range("LOB_PC"), 1, False)) Then
                        MsgBox UCase(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Profit Center for GL " & rng.value & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("Y" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("Y" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If

            End If
            If Left(rng.value, 1) = 6 Then
                Set CenterRng = Range("V" & rng.Row)
                If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(CenterRng) > 0 Then
                    MsgBox ("Operating expense accounts require a cost center")
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                    CenterRng.Select
                    GoTo SafeExit
                End If
            End If

            If Left(rng.value, 1) < 4 Then
                If Len(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
                    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Val(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value), Range("BS"), 1, False)) Then
                        MsgBox UCase(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Profit Center for GL " & rng.value & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("Y" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        Range("Y" & rng.Row).Select
                        GoTo SafeExit
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Range("I2").value = "Debits"
    Range("I3").value = "Credits"
    Range("I4").value = "Total"

    Range("J2").value = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("E8:E" & LastRow), "D", Range("F8:F" & LastRow)), 2)
    Range("J3").value = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("E8:E" & LastRow), "C", Range("F8:F" & LastRow)) * -1, 2)
    Range("J4").value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("J2:J3"))

    With Range("I2:J4").Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Range("I2:J4").BorderAround xlContinuous, xlMedium
    Range("J2:J4").Style = "Comma"

    If Not Range("J4").value = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Debits and Credits do not equal")
        GoTo SafeExit
    End If

    Sheet2.Shapes("Rounded Rectangle 3").Visible = msoTrue

    Sheet2.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("A8").Select

    MsgBox ("No errors found")

SafeExit:
    enable
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="secret", AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you happy with your program's speed? I have an answer if it's running slower than you'd like, but if it's running fine then it would be a waste of effort for you to implement.

Comment: It runs in the snap of a finger.  The reason for the refactor request is mainly cosmetic and to learn how to do something I don't know how to do yet.  Does your answer involve arrays, because I was told that was one way I can do it, but not sure how.

Comment: Yes, and dictionaries. I'd be happy to show you, I'll post that as an answer. Normally I'd say if you're already happy with your speed, it's not worth the trouble to refactor this particular program, but it's definitely worth the time to learn the concepts for later.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 6 → 5. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: I was able to utilize all the great feedback to revise my code and posted it [HERE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177466/check-accounting-journal-for-errors-revision) for final review.  I hope I didn't make too many more mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Must Change**:

- Use of unqualified `Range`.

  - *Example in your code*: `Range("D8:D" & LastRow)`
  - *What this means*: Unqualified means you didn't state the parent object. This is bad because the VB Editor will silently make assumptions for you. For example, if you just say `Range()`, the VBE assumes you mean `ThisWorkbook.Activesheet.Range()`. If you take the time to qualify every reference in the future, you will avoid bewildering errors where you have to guess what the VBE assumed for you.
  - *Fix*: You already know how to do it, use `With` blocks. For example, if you're talking about the sheet with the codename Sheet2, you could fully qualify the reference using `With` in the following three ways:

    - `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")`, assuming the sheet with codename Sheet2 is called "Sheet2" in your workbook.
    - `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)`, assuming the sheet with codename Sheet2 is the second sheet in your workbook.
    - `With Sheet2`, my favorite, referencing the sheet by its VBE codename. This means that if you change the sheet's name or reorder them, your macro will still work. I recommend giving `Sheet2` a new codename though. It looks like you're working with an accounting journal, so maybe `Journal`?

**Good to Change**

- Your repeated reads of the worksheet

  - *Example in your code*: `For Each rng In MainRng`, `If rng.value`
  - *What this means*: Every time you ask VBA to read or write a value to a worksheet, it is expensive performance-wise. If you're going to be doing it repeatedly, it's wise to save the sheet values to memory via an `array`.
  - *Fix*:

    ```
    'Use a better name, I'm just illustrating the concept
    Dim arrRangeToArray() as Variant 
    arrRangeToArray = rng.Value
    ```

    This will give you `rng` in two-dimensional, 1-based array form. You can work with these values much less expensively than when you read the worksheet directly.

    - Two dimensional array means it has both rows and columns
    - 1-based array means the first value will have the coordinates `1,1`, whereas a 0-based array would be `0,0`.

    Before you were using `For Each rng In MainRng`, `If rng.value`. To cycle through all the values in an array, you would do:

    ```
    Dim lngColumnIndex as Long
    'Columns are the second dimension, hence ",2"
    For lngColumnIndex = LBound(arrRangeToArray,2) to UBound(arrRangeToArray,2)
        Dim lngRowIndex as Long
        'Rows are the first dimension, hence ",1"
        For lngRowIndex = LBound(arrRangeToArray,1) to UBound(arrRangeToArray,1)
            If arrRangeToArray(lngRowIndex, lngColumnIndex) = "" Then
                'Whatever
            End If
        Next lngColumnIndex
    Next lngRowIndex
    ```
- Using VLookup to check for existence instead of a dictionary

  - *Example in your code*: `If IsError(Application.VLookup(rng.value, Range("Indicator"), 1, False))`
  - *What this means*: `WorksheetFunction`s like `VLookup`, `Count`, etc. are useful but expensive. As far as checking for existence in a range, you could save the range to a dictionary instead and then use the dictionary's `.Exists()` function.
  - *Fix*: First, go to the VBE's Tools menu, References, and check the box next to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Then building on the array code from before:

    ```
    'Initialize dictionary
    Dim dictRange As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictRange = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictRange.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    Dim lngColumnIndex as Long
    For lngColumnIndex = LBound(arrRangeToArray,2) to UBound(arrRangeToArray,2)
        Dim lngRowIndex as Long
        For lngRowIndex = LBound(arrRangeToArray,1) to UBound(arrRangeToArray,1)
            'Add range items to dictionary
            dictRange.Add Key:=arrRangeToArray(lngRowIndex, lngColumnIndex), Item:=arrRangeToArray(lngRowIndex, lngColumnIndex)
        Next lngColumnIndex
    Next lngRowIndex

    'Check if item exists in range
    If True = dictRange.Exists("value you're checking for here")
    ```

**Conclusion**

There's plenty of other things you could improve, but you're doing fine. I want to keep this review manageable for you - these three things are the most important in my opinion.

Comment: I usually do qualify ranges, but I was just working with the one sheet so I got lazy.  I see your point so I will update those and try and make it a habit.  The array and dictionary feedback are both interesting concepts and I will look into trying to implement those ideas once I can get a better grasp how it works.  Still fuzzy on the dictionary piece especially how it will work as a lookup tool.

Comment: @AshtonMorgan I'm with you - I definitely allow myself some space to get things done rather than get them perfect. I use `With` blocks aggressively to help me spend as little time qualifying my ranges as possible. Then it's just `.Range` instead of your existing `Range`.

Comment: @AshtonMorgan I'm really glad you liked my answer! FYI, one common suggestion around the StackExchange network is to not mark an answer as accepted until at least 24 hours after you ask to give yourself a better chance for multiple great answers. Hope that helps you in the future!

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 If I am not mistaken, something like `Foo = rng.Value` should make a 0-base array unless `Option Base 1` is at the top of the module. There are some instances where a 1-base array is made (though off the top of my head, I can't recall exactly when) but a range.value -> array isn't one of them. Just be careful :).

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 Also note that `Dim Foo() as Variant : Foo = Bar` is actually two separate variables. If you declare a `Foo()` you must use a `Foo()`. While somewhat stylistic (and it has some flaws) I prefer just declaring a `Foo as Variant` and then using logic checks before accessing it as an array. Lastly, I would recommend further explaining your use of `With` blocks to solve the object qualification. For example, if he did something like `With Foo : Bar = Range("A1").Value : End With` he would have the same issue because the real problem is that `Range()` is missing the `.` prefix.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Nope, taking the value of a Range object gives you a 2-dimensional 1-based array regardless of the `Option Base` setting. I always remember that because you can't have a row or column 0 in your spreadsheet.

Comment: @PatrickWynne Is correct. I was mistaken. That must've been the instance where it does create a 1-based array that I couldnt recall :).

Answer (score 5):

To not duplicate the good advice from puzzlepiece87, I would suggest also to look for pieces of code that look almost the same, with some minor changes (which can be passed as arguments to the function).

For instance:

```
If Len(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value) > 0 Then
    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Val(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value), Range("BS"), 1, False)) Then
        MsgBox UCase(Range("Y" & rng.Row).value) & " is not a valid Profit Center for GL " & rng.value & Chr(10) & "Check cell " & Range("Y" & rng.Row).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Range("Y" & rng.Row).Select
        GoTo SafeExit
    End If
End If
```

Can be extracted to:

```
Sub ValidateValue(columnId as String, message as String, comparissonValue as Integer, lookupRange as String)
    If Len(Range(columnID & rng.Row).value) > comparissonValue Then
        If IsError(Application.VLookup(Val(Range(columnId & rng.Row).value), Range(lookupRange), 1, False)) Then
            MsgBox message
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Range(columnId & rng.Row).Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End sub
```

And called from all the places you want. The construction of the message itself (which seems elaborate enough) can be made into another function, using a similar approach, and called from within this sub or from the main method, and passed as an argument (which is the approach I followed here).

What I want to stress out is that there's a lot of repetition here, and it looks more difficult to reuse that it really is. With some good parameter naming, and the better understanding of the business you should have, it shouldn't be that difficult. And as you extract more things, you'll see how things start to look simpler and to make more sense.

And yes, a side effect of this is having less lines of code. But for me this is not just about real estate. For me the idea behind extracting common functionality is more about simplifying your code and making it more legible, because as you find more common things that can be made into small subs or functions, your are clarifying what each part of your code does. For an external person, it would be easier to understand it. And it's also about reducing the likelihood of having bugs, because all the logic related to a single task is located in only one place, ideally very well named. So when you need to fix or modify anything related to that a task in your system, you know where to look at, and you apply fixes/changes in just one place (which is less prone to human error than having to do it in several places scattered all over the place, which might not be very visible or easy to find).

By the way, after you extracted the common code to some smaller functions and subs, you'll also see that applying all other advice is far easier!

Comment: This makes sense.  I would be replacing the if statements with one sub, but just calling the same sub over and over instead of multiple if statements which will save a lot of real estate.  I will give this a try, thanks.

Comment: @carlossiera Sorry for the duplication in my answer. I did not see yours whilie I have been writing mine for some time.

Comment: @AshtonMorgan I just updated my answer to clarify a little bit why I think this is a good approach.

Comment: @M.Doerner it's ok. We are both here to help the OP.

Comment: `GoTo` can't jump outside a procedure scope, that extracted `ValidateValue` method needs a `SafeExit` label, or better, an `Exit Sub` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug. You are right. Didn't pay much attention to detail, as I was just trying to make a point on refactoring. I just fixed it!

Answer (score 5):

@puzzlepiece87 already gave some good suggestions. I would like to add a few of my own. I will start with some general programming guidelines which are always good to follow; then I will give some examples how to apply them to your code; finally, I will make some more suggestions that came to my mind.

### General Programming Guidelines

1. One of the most useful, and hardest to get right, guidelines for programming is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP). In short, it says that every unit of your code should do one thing and only one. The exact formulation is a bit more sophisticated but this description is a good approximation. The primary benefit is that following this principle makes your code much more readable. In particular, you can substitute comments, which tend to get stale over time, into procedure and function names.
2. Somewhat related to the SRP is the DRY principle. (Don't repeat yourself.) More practically, do not write very similar code twice without thinking about a way to deal with the situation by a bit more abstracting.
3. The second best advice is to give good names to variables and procedures. This helps readability again. In general, longer more descriptive names are better than short cryptic ones.
4. For readability, and hence maintainability, `GoTo` is a statement from hell. When it is used outside an error handling statement, it either does something terrible or something that could be more cleanly expressed by another construct.
5. Errors are raised for a reason. They usually tell you that something is broken. So, do not disable them for extended periods.

### How these Guidelines Relate to your Code

Let me start with the naming. This is actually not too bad. As already stated by @puzzlepiece87, you could rename the document module `Sheet2` but otherwise you seem to try to use meaningful names.

One thing you might want to do is follow a widely used case convention for names in VBA. That would be camelCase for variables and PascalCase for Functions and Procedures. This makes distinguishing the different types of constructs rather easy.

One other thing regarding names: you can give names to ranges on spreadsheets. This allows you to refer to them in the VBA code like in `Range("MyRange")`. This does not only improve readability, but also makes your code more immune to failure due to changes in the sheet's design, e.g. adding a column. (Oh, I just realized you actually do that for some ranges.) Note that you can actually define named ranges dynamically via the names dialog. (You can use `OFFSET`.) Unfortunately, this feature seems to crash Excel quite rather too often.

Now, let me come to your use of `GoTo`. This is actually not the sort of `GoTo` that is horrifically bad but it basically hints at a SRP violation. Your procedure has the responsibility to disable updating, unlocking the sheet and the actual work it does. You can easily avoid using `GoTo` by extracting the entire work into a procedure that is called by an enclosing one responsible for the logistics. The surrounding procedure would look something like this.

```
Public Sub ErrorCheck()
    Disable
    UnprotectSheet ActiveSheet, "secret"
    DoActualWork
    ProtectSheet ActiveSheet, "secret"
    Enable
End Sub
```

Btw, never put anything that should really be secret in code. (Here, it does not seem too bad since it is only the sheet protection which is not secure anyway.)

Admittedly, introducing separate procedures for protecting and unprotecting the sheet is a bit overkill, but in principle you could take further measures in these procedures relating to the sheet in question.

Having the procedure above allows you to simply use `Exit Sub` instead of `GoTo SafeExit` in `DoActualWork`. Moreover the responsibilities got separated so that it is clearer what each part is doing.

Regarding the SRP, there is more to say about you procedure. It actually does a lot of different things. One good indication what would be good to pull into its own procedure or function is when you feel the urge to insert a comment as heading. You could literally turn your comments into procedure names like `MakeDebitAndCreditEntriesUppercase` and pull the code into its own procedure. Then, the main procedure reads like a higher level description of what is going on; the details are in the implementations of the extracted procedures. When you come back to your code after a few months, you will thank yourself for doing this.

You could abstract conditions away into a function like

```
Private Function IsValidRange(evaluationRange As Excel.Range, interdectionRange As Excel.Range, referenceRangeName As String)
     IsValidRange = (Not Application.Intersect(evaluationRange,interdectionRange) Is Nothing) Then
        If IsError(Application.VLookup(evaluationRange.value, Range(referenceRangeName), 1, False)) Then
End Function
```

In a similar fashion you can try to tackle all those `Len(someRange)>0` conditions.

Since you generally do the same thing after finding an error, just with another error text or range to select, you can also put tin in its own private procedure, which you can call every time one of the tests returns true.

### Some Further Suggestions

As already stated by @puzzlepiece87, it is always a good idea to state things explicitly instead of letting the VBE infer it. That also holds for the accessibility of procedures. Your procedure is implicitly public; you should simply state that in the code by explicitly applying the modifier.

The basic problem that led you to your usage of `GoTo` was probably that you have to do some clean up after your processing. There is a neat little trick coming from C++ you can use to handle such situations, the RAII principle (Resource Allocation is Instantiation). This mean that you couple acquiring and releasing a resource or a temporary change of settings with the creation and destruction of an object. This works in VBA, in contrast to Java or C#, because objects in VBA have a well-defined lifetime.

To apply this principle, you insert a new class module. Let us call it `UpdateDisabler`. Then you move `enable`, `disable` and the fields they use into the class as private members. Finally you add a `Class_Initialize` procedure calling `disable` and a `Class_Terminate` procedure calling `enable`.

Now, if you want to disable updating, you create a new instance of `UpdateDisabler` and assign it to a variable. Creating the instance makes VBA call `Class_Initialize` and hence `disable`. Once the variable goes out of scope, more precisely, once no object in scope holds a reference to the instance, VBA automatically calls `Class_Terminate` and hence `enable`. This way, the settings get enabled again no matter what.

Comment: thanks for the detailed and thorough answer.  I have already read it several times.  I believe I will be reading it several more times, because there is a lot of valuable information, advice, and insights that I want to learn, practice, and utilize in my coding.  I never took any computer science classes and these principles you mention make me think maybe I should sign up for some.  Again, thanks for all the help.  There were several things you mentioned that I really need to dig into deeper like the class module and replacing nested if statements with function.

Comment: @AshtonMorgan To be honest, in most CS classes these principles are not taught. Instead, I can wholeheartedly recommend to read   _Clean Code_ by _Robert Martins_ aka _Uncle Bob_. That is the book that thought me how to really program.

Comment: that sounds good, I will check out that book, thanks again